# Find string in another string using python

Tags: python

Lets say that you have an email address xxx@yyy.com and you want to create something like this in python:

```
email = 'mystuff@yyy.com'
try:
    if "@yyy.com":
    #do something

    if "@zzz.com":
    #do something else
except:
#do something
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
email_addr = "foo@yyy.com"

if email_addr.endswith("@yyy.com"):
    # do something
elif email_addr.endswith("@zzz.com"):
    # do something else

# or...

if "@yyy.com" in email_addr:
    # do something
elif "@zzz.com" in email_addr:
    # do something else
```

Comment: for some reason this isn't working. is there something that I'm missing? what library does this use?

Comment: It doesn't use any library; these are all part of the standard Python distribution.

Answer (score 0):

```
email = "xxx@yyy.com"
if "@yyy.com" in email:
#do something

if "@zzz.com" in email:
#do something else
```